# How do you access an SQL Server sequence from PowerShell with invoke-sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

In my sql server 12.0 I have created a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SESSIONI_dv_seq] 
 AS [bigint]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE -9223372036854775808
 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
 CYCLE 
 CACHE;
```

sql server management studio works perfectly:

```
select Next value for  dbo.SESSIONI_dv_seq
```

return the correct value.

At this point, in a powershell script I want to obtain a new sequence value using invoke-sqlcmd

```
$DataSet = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database "alglogistica" -Query "SELECT SESSIONI_dv_seq_value=next value for dbo.sessioni_dv_seq;" -ServerInstance  "10.81.104.185\SQL14"
```

This statement doesn't work (without no error returned by the script).

I have tried other selects in the query and these work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$result = Invoke-SQLCmd -Database alglogistica `
    -query "SELECT next value for dbo.sessioni_dv_seq as SESSIONI_dv_seq_value" `
    -serverinstance  "10.81.104.185\SQL14"
$id = $result.SESSIONI_dv_seq_value
```